# Principles of Biomedical Informatics in SBCL: what's wrong with this let?

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp, let

Lisp noob here, inclined to believe I am certainly misunderstanding something as this is a problem from page 35 of a rather long book on its second edition. I have been reading up on `let` binding, so let me make sure the author's* intent is clear by quoting him:

> In the following code, the symbol `pos` serves as a temporary storage
>   or variable that has as its value the result of the `position`
>   function expression. Finally, how will we accumulate the results? The recursive call should give us a list of the remaining positions, so the first one found should just be put on the front. We already have a function to do this, the `cons` function

This is the code:

```
(defun all-pos (item seq start)
  (let ((pos (position item seq :start start))
    (if pos
        (cons pos
          (all-pos item seq (+ 1 pos)))
    nil))))
```

and this is the error:

```
Ch1_Notes.lisp:27:5:
  error: 
    The LET binding spec (IF POS
                             (CONS POS (ALL-POS ITEM SEQ (+ 1 POS)))
                             NIL) is malformed.

Compilation failed.
```

Is this self-evidently wrong? Is there some preceding code I should be including as well?

*The author, Ira J. Kalet, is dead, so I can't ask him.

Comment: It is indeed an error, but it is fixed in the following versions of the code in the next pages (page 25-27) (https://books.google.fr/books/about/Principles_of_Biomedical_Informatics.html?id=AdKtkKcWF-gC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=position&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answerers before me mentioned, a simple parenthesis problem:

```
;; correct version:

(defun all-pos (item seq start)
  (let ((pos (position item seq :start start)))
     (if pos
         (cons pos
               (all-pos item seq (+ 1 pos)))
  nil)))

;; e.g.
(all-pos '3 '(1 2 3 4 3 5 4) 0)
;; returns (2 4) - correctly
```

Comment: sorry, now corrected. (I corrected in the terminal but copied the wrong thing in the editor I guess). By the way, I wanted to buy ths book, too. :)

Comment: Thank you, that runs. I do like the book, especially since the content is relevant to my training and work. I'm a little disappointed that this error made it through the editing of two editions, but I get the sense a healthy respect for parens is a basic attriibute of a lisp programmer, and suspicion of someone else's code, even the book author's, is good.

Answer (score 3):

Often it is useful to re-indent the code if there is such an error. One typically can do it in the editor with a key-command.

But Lisp also comes in with built in code formatting, called *pretty printing*:

```
CL-USER > (let ((*print-right-margin* 60))
 (pprint '

; your code follows:

(defun all-pos (item seq start)
  (let ((pos (position item seq :start start))
    (if pos
        (cons pos
          (all-pos item seq (+ 1 pos)))
    nil))))

))
```

The output looks like this:

```
(DEFUN ALL-POS (ITEM SEQ START)
  (LET ((POS (POSITION ITEM SEQ :START START))
        (IF POS (CONS POS (ALL-POS ITEM SEQ (+ 1 POS)))
         NIL))))
```

This makes it easier to see that the `if` is on the same indentation level like the `pos` variable binding. **This can't be right!**

To format your code with Lisp you just need:

```
(let ((*print-right-margin* 60))
  (pprint '

; here goes your code

))
```

and Lisp will format it for you...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the unbalanced parantheses problem going on. A way to see that is to look at the closing parenthesis after NIL. That closes the IF statement. After that one there are two more closing ones that would close the LET and DEFUN. However, you still have one more after that. That is what is causing the issue.